# Android Text Input Validation on Backend/other Process

Tags: android, validation, input, android-edittext, ipc

I had some questions on running text input validation that the user types in Android (EditText) in another process. I know ideally it would be better to have it within the same application but the input validation needs to be checked on the other process, no way around this...

I have the inter-process communication setup already, thats not a problem. Additionally I know of the text input listener for the EditText whenever a user types a key so thats not a problem. Here IS the problem, I need to run text validation every time the user types in a character and if the character doesn't pass validation, I need to make it so the character is never typed.

As you know I cannot do this check on the UI thread, but at the same time I need to 'hault' user input until validation is complete. How do I do this? I am a bit lost here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So What I do instead is set an input filter on the EditText view. Then I keep some flags set (validate) for when I'm doing the check on the back end. I use this flag as a check if the user enters input before validation has completed. I ignore there input and return an empty character (which inserts nothing of what they asked). Its a bit clunky but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use two remote services - one for telling another process about user entering text and the other - as callback from remote process (implemented in your app). You bind to remote service, register callback (Google Remote service example https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.java) and modify edit text state in this callback.
There is also very convenient way to handle user input by using RxJava library - use .debounce() operator to not to fould remote process after every edited symbol.

Comment: so I have a thrift connection to my other process. I can call, using my thrfit IF, boolean valid = input.validateInput(x) where 'x' is the input character and returns a bool if valid input or not. Obviously to do this 'input.validateInput(x)' it has to run outside of the UI thread. The only thing I can think of is to listen to character input event, disable keyboard, perform check in seperate thread, post result in UI thread which would then enable keyboard and send input through.... Seems clunky. Your ReactiveX library looks really interesting,may require a good chunk of time to learn.

Comment: So i looked more into that RxJava you mentioned. I think I'm going to use it in other areas but in this situation I don't think it helps me. I need to essentially not allow the user to type anything after they hit a key so I can do the check, then if it passes, allow user to keep typing